# Xcode 6 beta: I'm not able to select Swift as language

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I created a new project and selected Cocoa App and pressed next and found that Objective C was the only language available. I clicked on Help | What's new in Xcode Menu and it says that the swift language and lang support are the new features.

What's wrong here?

UPDATE: I updated the product from the Apple site. Despite the documentation that came with Xcode saying that Swift is part of this release, why can't I get to use swift? By the way, the Xcode version is: Version 6.0 (6A313).

Comment: Still beta? final edition is released.

Comment: I downloaded it just a week ago. Am I missing something ?

Comment: the current latest version is 6.1 (6A1027)

Comment: You chose OS X cocoa application right?

Comment: @Carpsen90 : Yes, that's what I chose. However, when I click on the drop-down, I only get Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is explained in [the Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=14):

> Today is the GM date for Swift on iOS. We have one more GM date to go for Mac. Swift for OS X currently requires the SDK for OS X Yosemite, and when Yosemite ships later this fall, Swift will also be GM on the Mac. In the meantime, you can keep developing your Mac apps with Swift by downloading the beta of [Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

So, you need Xcode 6.1, not 6.0. According to the [download page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) at the moment, 6.1 will work on either the Yosemite Developer Preview or Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

You need now Yosemite to develop Cocoa Apps is Swift.

Comment: that's not what I've seen on apple's website or other sites

Comment: Look at [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1037309#1037309) and [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1037292#1037292).

Comment: This and this cannot be opened without [this](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action) :P

Comment: Someone who has access to Xcode 6 should also have access to the Apple dev forums.