# Coudn't select language swift in OS x Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: swift

In `file->newproject -> osx ->` selected Cocoa. Now started entering product name and all related details.

At the part of language I couldn't select Swift. It's not changing from Objective C . I don't know why. Please help me to find out this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 6 beta : I'm not able to select swift as language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931469/xcode-6-beta-im-not-able-to-select-swift-as-language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think 6.0.1 was iOS only. For Mac OS X I believe you need to use Xcode 6.1 beta 2 to be able to use Swift.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

EDIT: 01 Oct 2014: The release, today, of Xcode 6.1 GM Seed supercedes the above - same link though.